# PyTorch error loading saved nn.Module: object has no attribute 'to'

Tags: pytorch

**I am using PyTorch 0.4**.

I defined a PyTorch `MyModel` by inheriting from `nn.Module`, and saved an instance of it by calling

`torch.save(my_model, my_path)`

Then, when loading it again with `torch.load(my_path)`, my program crashed with the following error:

`AttributeError: 'MyModel' object has no attribute 'to'`

But my program was able to run it in previous stages. What did go wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I already found it out, and just wanted to quickly post about it since google didn't give an obvious clue.

It turned out that, although I saved the model from a computer with 0.4, I was trying to load it from a different computer that **still had an older (<0.4) PyTorch version installed**. `pip install --upgrade torch` fixed it.

---

I found it out because the `my_model.train()`and `.eval()` methods were indeed working, so I remembered that the `.to()` method was introduced in 0.4. Useful references:

- https://pytorch.org/2018/04/22/0_4_0-migration-guide.html
- https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/loading-pytorch-model-without-a-code/12469