# Problems setting up FastAi working on Colab

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory, torchvision

I'm trying to work through a tutorial on [CycleGANs](https://towardsdatascience.com/cyclegans-to-create-computer-generated-art-161082601709) using the Colab platform but I'm struggling to find a way through the 'simple' part of just importing libraries.

I'm just trying to import the following:

```
from fastai.conv_learner import *
from fastai.dataset import *
from cgan.options.train_options import *
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from cgan.options.train_options import TrainOptions
from cgan.data.data_loader import CreateDataLoader
from cgan.models.models import create_model
from cgan.util.visualizer import Visualizer
from google_images_download import google_images_download
```

I'm currently stuck with an error on the first line:

```
----> 7 class IntermediateLayerGetter(nn.ModuleDict):
      8     """
      9     Module wrapper that returns intermediate layers from a model

AttributeError: module 'torch.nn' has no attribute 'ModuleDict'
```

The code can be found online: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1dMQWStzLfAHDTGuKaUNQn1aOBWeJw4FN

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51306585/pytorch-error-loading-saved-nn-module-object-has-no-attribute-to) it sorts partially the problem.

Afterthat I received and this error (Detected that PyTorch and torchvision were compiled with different CUDA versions. PyTorch has CUDA Version=9.0 and torchvision has CUDA Version=10.0. Please reinstall the torchvision that matches your PyTorch install.) and solve it with

```
pip install torch==1.0.1 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu100/stable
```

I hope it helps :)